# How to fix ad content in is not consistent with the app's content rating play console?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, admob, google-play-console

My app got **removed** from play store when I updated the **screenshots**. Under an Issue "ad content in your app is **not consistent** with the app's content rating".

Here's the full **message** I got when I made an appeal.

```
We’ve reviewed your appeal request and found that your app, <app name> (com.package, App Bundle Version: 3), still violates Google Play Policy. We’ve included details below about the specific issue with your app and what you can do to get your app back on Google Play.

Step 1: Fix the policy violation with your app

During review, we found an issue with the ad content in your app.

The ad content in your app is not consistent with the app's content rating. To fix this issue, please remove content not consistent with your app’s rating and/or retake the content rating questionnaire. If you monetize your app, please ensure you’ve excluded ads from sensitive categories. For more details, you can refer to the “Ads” section (#4) of the Families Policy Requirements.

Please refer to the attached screenshot for further information. 

Before resubmitting your app for further review, please make sure to DEACTIVATE the non-compliant version (App Bundle Version: 3) and increment the version number of APK. You may also want to double-check that your app complies with all other Developer Program policies as additional enforcement could occur if there are further policy violations.

Step 2: Submit your app for another review

Read through the Ads section (#4) of the Families Policy Requirements and the Ads and Monetization policy.

Make appropriate changes to your app, and be sure to address the issue described above.

Double-check that your app is compliant with all other Developer Program policies.

Sign in to your Play Console account, upload the modified, policy-compliant APK across all tracks, and deactivate the noncompliant APK(s).

To deactivate a noncompliant APK, please create a new release and upload a compliant APK to the same track.
Be sure to increment the APK version number and set the release to 100% rollout, in order to successfully override and deactivate the noncompliant APK.
```

I have tried these **solutions**:

1. Admob > App > select app > Blocking controls > Ad content rating > `General audience.`
2. Admob > App > select app > Blocking controls > `Sensitive categories` > all disabled.

but none of these solve my issue.

They gave me this **image** as it include the **problem** but I can't realize it
[image]

I have submitted the update twice and I got `rejected`.

How can I solve this, thanks